# Qual a diferença entre Ajax.BeginForm e Html.BeginForm no Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Trabalhando com web em`asp.net mvc`, vi que há possibilidade de se utilizar `Ajax.BeginForm()` e `Html.BeginForm()`.

Qual a diferença entre o método do `Ajax` e o do `Html`?

Answer (score 6):

Basicamente, um constrói um formulário usando Ajax, e o outro constrói um formulário simples, ambos em HTML.

Em formulários Ajax, o envio da requisição é feito por JavaScript e normalmente não há transição da página corrente: apenas atualização dos elementos exibidos com acréscimo, modificação ou exclusão deles. A transição pode ser feita *a posteriori* usando código JavaScript adicional, se for o caso.

Formulários simples supõem uma transição de página e normalmente funcionam com apenas dois verbos: `POST` (cujos valores do formulário não são inclusos na URL) e `GET` (cujos valores estão na URL).